# Connect Service - Are all Documents returned as PDFs?

Tags: docusignapi

In the connect service, are all documents, regardless of their original type returned as PDF?

For example, send a jpg for signing. Will a PDF be returned via the connect service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all documents in a Connect message will be PDF format.  In fact, all files (regardless of original format) are converted to PDF format as soon as they're submitted to DocuSign (during the file upload process when creating an Envelope), and will be PDF format from then on out -- whether viewed via the DocuSign console, viewed via a DocuSign "Envelope Completion" email, or accessed via a DocuSign Connect message.